# Which data do I send wrong?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My incoming JSON object:

```json
{
    "date": "2018-10-10", 
    "fiche": 1, 
    "fiche_type": 2, 
    "description": "test", 
    "project_code": "444", 
    "invoces": 
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "Ol",
            "amount": 300,
            "type": "debit"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "type" :"credit",
            "description": "Ol2",
            "amount": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Validation rules are:

```php
public function rules()
{

    return [
        'date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        'fiche' => 'required|integer',
        'fiche_type' => 'required|integer',
        'description' => 'string',
        'project_code' => 'string',
        'invoices' => 'required|array',
        'invoices.id' => 'required|integer',
        'invoices.description' => 'string',
        'invoices.amount' => 'required|numeric',
        'invoices.type' => 'required|string',
    ];
}
```

I always get a common error as: Wrong data validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check closely to your validation rules, specifically:

```
return [
    // ...
    'invoices' => 'required|array',
    'invoices.id' => 'required|integer', // <---
    'invoices.description' => 'string', // <---
    'invoices.amount' => 'required|numeric', // <---
    'invoices.type' => 'required|string', // <---
];
```

With that setup, something like this should pass the validation (at least that part):

```
$invoices = [
        'id' => 123,
        'description' => 'a description',
        'amount' => 123,
        'type' => 'a type',
    ];
```

**but that is not what you want**.. you need to actually validate an array of items (array) with that structure:

```
$invoices = [
    [
        'id' => 123,
        'description' => 'a description',
        'amount' => 123,
        'type' => 'a type',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 345,
        'description' => 'another description',
        'amount' => 156,
        'type' => 'another type',
    ],
];
```

**So.. what is the problem?**

Well, before the item keys, you need to access the *key of the item itself*, but given that this rules will apply for every item in the array you need to make use of a wildcard. As the documentation says:

> You may also validate each element of an array. For example, to
>   validate that each e-mail in a given array input field is unique, you
>   may do the following:
>
> ```
> $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
>     'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
>     'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
> ]);
> ```
>
> Likewise, you may use the * character when specifying your validation
>   messages in your language files, making it a breeze to use a single
>   validation message for array based fields:
>
> ```
> 'custom' => [
>     'person.*.email' => [
>         'unique' => 'Each person must have a unique e-mail address',
>     ] ],
> ```

So in your case:

```
return [
    // ...
    'invoices' => 'required|array',
    'invoices.*.id' => 'required|integer', // <---
    'invoices.*.description' => 'string', // <---
    'invoices.*.amount' => 'required|numeric', // <---
    'invoices.*.type' => 'required|string', // <---
];
```

Check the [Validation Arrays section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays) of the documentation.